# Cannot get function with 'get' part in Firestore rules to work correctly

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my Firestore rules, I have the following function:

```
//True if the current user is 1 of the admins of this event, false otherwise
function isAnAdminOfEvent(){
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.mail in resource.data.admins;
  //return "eUB5Lnl5" in resource.data.admins;
}
```

Somehow, this rule always fails. When I comment the first line and comment out the last line, the rule is working fine. Note that I'm sure that the current user object does have the mail attribute which is set to "eUB5Lnl5".

The users object has the following get permission:

```
match /users/{userId} {
       allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId; //users can only read their own data
}
```

Remark: this is the first part of my rules definition in which I use a 'get' method. I'm probably doing something wrong here...

**Added on request in the comments:**

The test code that currently fails is the following:

```
//Check that event admins are allowed to update other data of the event, such as the description or color
    CompletableFuture<Boolean> futureEventAdminChangeAction = new CompletableFuture<>();
    mFieldsMap.clear();
    mFieldsMap.put(DESCRIPTION, "An updated description!");
    mFieldsMap.put(COLOR, 3);
    mFieldsMap.put(NAME, "The new name");
    FireUtilEvents.getEvent( key ).set( mFieldsMap, SetOptions.merge()).addOnCompleteListener(task -> futureEventAdminChangeAction.complete( task.isSuccessful() ));
    Assert.assertEquals( true, futureEventAdminChangeAction.get() );
```

In the test I'm verifing that an event admin is allowed to update an event for which he is an admin. The update rule of the event data is the following:

```
allow update: if isNoEventOwnerChange() && 
            (isOwner() || (isAnAdminOfEvent() && isNotForbiddenAdminChange()));
```

In the test:

- isNoEventOwnerChange() returns true,
- isOwner() returns false,
- isNotForbiddenAdminChange() return true,
- isAnAdminOfEvent() return **false** (which is unexpected).

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to access the data in Firestore?

Comment: Is your function `isAnAdminOfEvent` defined in the block `match /databases/{database}/documents`?

Comment: Can you share the structure of the data you are trying to send? Looks like `mail` property could be nested and therefore it isn't being validated

Comment: Hi @Laurent, many thanks for your remark! I found out that I nested the functions within my rules one level to high (at the same level as the `match /databases/{database}/document` instead of within. Moving the functions one block deeper directly fixed the problem.

Comment: Welcome! I have added an answer so that people with the same issue get the idea quickly. Please mark as resolved it if you think it is relevant. Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the definition of your function `isAnAdminOfEvent` in `match /databases/{database}/documents` block.